# How to properly use plain SQL code in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, gis, pgadmin, wkb

I'm using pgadmin right now and this is the table I created. I'm trying to convert this wkb_geometry column into lat,lon geometry point.

When I tried to select this column and declare it as a variable so I can perform some conversion on it, I failed to do so by using plain SQL code such as "DECLARE @xxx VarChar". I looked it up and did see that plain SQL code doesn't always work in Postgres but haven't found a solution yet. Could someone point me a way to do it? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code and the table definition.

Comment: `DECLARE @xxx VarChar` is not plain SQL code, it is T-SQL per [DECLARE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Therefore only available in SQL Server and Sybase per [Transact-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL).

Comment: If you are using [postgis](https://postgis.net/), then you can look at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95373/convert-geometry-to-latitude-longitude-using-postgis-st-transform) for solutions on how to convert geometry to lat long.